# Paging a gridview with IEnumerable object as datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to paginate a gridview that has been loaded with IEnumerable object a datasource, i have the following error message: *the data source does not support server-side data paging*

I am not using ObjectDatasource, i populate the gridview with code behind like this:

```
Gridview.Datasource = MyDataSource;
Gridview.Databind();
```

MyDatasarce is a IEnumarable list of object.
i am using visual studio 2015 and C# 7

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a `PageIndexChanging` event.

Say your gridview ID is `ID="gvMain"`

Within the asp:Gridview tag you will have something like

```
OnPageIndexChanging="gvMain_PageIndexChanging"
```

Also add `AllowPaging="True"`

In the code behind you will have something like:

```
protected void gvMain_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        gvMain.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvMain.DataBind();
}
```